# How to add ipv6 to Google cloud firewall rules

Tags: firewall, ipv6, google-cloud-platform

I have a firewall which I only allow specific ipv4 clients to access to.

Unfortunately Google network does not allow ipv6 IP addresses within the network.

Is there a way around this so that I can also allow ipv6 addresses?

Not ideal but I can disable the firewall altogether.

Comment: It's unclear what IPv6 traffic it is that you want to allow. Are you referring to GCE? In that case the only IPv6 traffic supported at this time is for HTTP, HTTPS, SSL Proxy, and TCP Proxy load balancing: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ipv6

Comment: Http and https. The problem is I cannot add ipv6 to the GCE whitelist.

Comment: @kasperd still not sure how I can allow ipv6 traffic to my server. The GCE firewall is not supported by ipv6

Comment: @GokhanDilek You don't: https://serverfault.com/a/893681/37475

Answer (score 2):

> [All VPC networks use the IPv4 protocol. Compute Engine networks currently do not support IPv6. However, Google is a major advocate of IPv6 and it is an important future direction.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#networks)

In other words, IPv6 is not supported on Compute Engine, period. Global load balancers support IPv6 connectivity to clients, but they will communicate with your Compute Engine resources using IPv4 only.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) says:

> Firewall rules
>
> You must create a firewall rule that allows traffic from 130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 to reach your instances. This rule allows traffic from both the load balancer and the health checker. The rule must allow traffic on the port your global forwarding rule has been configured to use, and your health checker should be configured to use the same port. If your health checker uses a different port, then you must create another firewall rule for that port.
>
> Note that firewall rules block and allow traffic at the instance level, not at the edges of the network. They cannot prevent traffic from reaching the load balancer itself.

Connections from the internet to the HTTP/HTTPS load balancer can be IPv4 or IPv6 (assuming you have assigned an address from each family to the load balancer). Connections from the load balancer to the VMs are at this time only IPv4 and will originate from one of the ranges mentioned in the documentation. The client IP address is sent in an HTTP header and can be either IPv4 or IPv6.

The firewall will only see the IPv4 address of the load balancer, not the client. If your VMs have external IP addresses and you don't want to allow clients to bypass the load balancer, you can use firewall rules to only allow HTTP/HTTPS connections from the IP range allocated for load balancers and health checks.

Comment: This, but it should be noted that firewall rules do not affect the load balancer itself, since it sits outside the VPC network.

Comment: @Alex Correct. That's also what the citation from the documentation says in slightly different words.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud now supports external ipv6 on VM instances. Each instance can get a /96 external ip range and it can be used to access internet (without NAT) or be used for VM to VM traffic.

At this moment (July 2021) it's only supported limited regions:

- asia-east1
- asia-south1
- europe-west2
- us-west2

See more detailed in

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ipv6-addresses

VPC firewall rules also supports IPv6 now:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#specifications

> - Firewall rules support IPv4 connections. IPv6 connections are also supported in VPC networks that have IPv6 enabled. When specifying a source for an ingress rule or a destination for an egress rule by address, you can specify IPv4 or IPv6 addresses or blocks in CIDR notation.
> - Each firewall rule can contain either IPv4 or IPv6 ranges, but not both.